# Combining match groups from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbMatch1 (_Key_out int, reference int, dataset varchar(100), drivinglicense varchar(100), name varchar(100), dateofbirth datetime)
INSERT INTO dbMatch1 values (1,1,'Sales', '','Richard Williams','1980-11-07')
INSERT INTO dbMatch1 values  (1,86,'Production', '','Richard Williams','1980-11-07')
INSERT INTO dbMatch1 values( 1,1008,'Finance', 'jdhdhdh8333','Richard Williams','1980-11-07')
INSERT INTO dbMatch1 values (2,90,'Marketing', '','Dick Williams','1980-11-07')
INSERT INTO dbMatch1 values (3,251,'Sales', '','Ian McWilliams','1971-02-02')

CREATE TABLE dbMatch2 (_Key_out int, reference int, dataset varchar(100), DrivingLicense varchar(100),name varchar(100), dateofbirth datetime)

INSERT INTO dbMatch2 values (100,1008,'Finance', 'jdhdhdh8333','Richard Williams','1980-11-07')
INSERT INTO dbMatch2 values (100,90,'Marketing', 'jdhdhdh8333','','')
INSERT INTO dbMatch2 values (100,95,'Sales', 'jdhdhdh8333','','')
INSERT INTO dbMatch2 values (101,45,'Production', 'jlbfjldfnl','','')
INSERT INTO dbMatch2 values (102,455,'Marketing', 'jlbfjldfnl','','')
```

The _key_out column identifies records that are duplicates.  Sales record 1, Production record 86 and Finance record 1008 are duplicates from dbMatch1 and Finance record 1008, Marketing record 90 and Sales record 95 are duplicates from dbMatch 2.

How do I combine these results? For example, I would like the first three records from dbMatch1 and the first two records from dbMatch2 to be part of the same group.

I have tried this:

select * from dbmatch1
union
select * from dbmatch2

The problem is that the _key_out ids are not the same for the following rows:

```
1   1   Sales       Richard Williams    1980-11-07 00:00:00.000
1   86  Production      Richard Williams    1980-11-07 00:00:00.000
1   1008    Finance jdhdhdh8333 Richard Williams    1980-11-07 00:00:00.000
100 90  Marketing   jdhdhdh8333     1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
100 95  Sales   jdhdhdh8333     1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
100 1008    Finance jdhdhdh8333 Richard Williams    1980-11-07 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what have you tried but can't you use `UNION` to merge the result like

```
(select * from dbmatch1) -- giving first part duplicates

UNION

(select * from dbmatch2) -- giving second part duplicates
```

Comment: The matched records would have different group ids.

Comment: You mean different no of column (or) type of column? in that case it will be difficult to merge them.

Comment: I have updated the DDL in my OP.  Please take a look.

Comment: You said in post `_key_out ids are not the same`. Why would that be a issue? I am bit confused here.

Comment: The _key_out field identifies records that are duplicates. The duplicates span both tables. Therefore they need the same _key_out values.